# Detect Camera Angle for AR

Tags: javascript, android, augmented-reality, euler-angles, wikitude

I am using Wikitude currently for my AR Project. I have a Video Drawable above my picture target and I want to the video to adjust based on the angle of the camera from the target. I have tried the heading,roll,and tilt functions. They work fine, I want to those values to adjust base on the camera angle. I already asked the forums but there is no concrete reply about my query. I want to know if it can be achieved or not. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the Wikitude Support forum: http://www.wikitude.com/developer/developer-forum/-/message_boards/view_message/429589

this is currently not possible. It has been put on our feature request list for internal discussion.

For future support requests I kindly ask you to use a single channel (wikitude developer forum or stack overflow).